# Hibernate @ManyToOne/@JoinColumn optimization

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a Hibernate entity that is comprised of many other entities that are used within the application. The other entities that make up this `MainEntity` are joined by using `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn`. This `MainEntity` class has 5 columns (`@Column`) and 7 `@ManyToOne`/`@JoinColumn` entities that are used.

I seem to be running into performance issues when retrieving all of these `MainEntity` classes. We want to serialize the `MainEntity` to JSON as well as the other entities that are associated with it. Note that there aren't that many that we are retrieving - less than 30 total.

Below is an example of what the class looks like along with my `findAll()` method to retrieve these classes. I know that `@ManyToOne` is `EAGER` by default, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to get all of these entities that is easier on the system. Thank you in advance.

```
@Entity(name = "MainEntity")
@Table(name = "main_entity")
public class MainEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  // Other @Columns defined here

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity_1_id")
  private Entity1 entity1;

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity_2_id")
  private Entity2 entity2;

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity_3_id")
  private Entity3 entity3;

  // ... and so on, for a total of 7 @ManyToOne() columns
}
```

Here is the `findAll()` method that I have:

```
final List<E> findAllOrdered(Class<E> clazz, Order order) {
    final Session session = sessionManager.openNewSession();
    try {
        return session.createCriteria(clazz)
                .addOrder(order)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                .list();
    } finally {
        sessionManager.closeSession(session);
    }
}
```

I found myself having to add the `Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY` because we were getting duplicate `MainEntity` results if a child had multiple associated with it. I suspect this is big part of my performance problem.

Comment: use Hibernate 2nd level cache

Comment: Don't you think all those ManyToOne relationships, are having an impact on performance. There seems to be a lot of them. Also do they have relationships of their own that are eager loaded?

Comment: How many queries the findAll method is firing? Is it not using any join? Why you think it is a perfect bottleneck? And do you not want to load ManyToOne associations?

Comment: @CholNhial - yes, I do for sure think that they are causing an issue, I just don't know the best way to deal with it. A couple of those relationships do have others that are EAGER. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu - It's firing a lot, I enabled SQL debugging through Hibernate and it's doing a ton of `left outer join` calls it seems. I think my issue, that Chol pointed out, is that a few of the relationships that are mapped are also eagerly loading data.

Comment: @joshft91 I would prefer to make associations Lazy by default. And join them in HQL/criteria based on which association we really want to fetch. Also before that see the number of SQLs it is firing, are they really reqd, are the queries tuned etc and accordingly decide on LAZY vs EAGER.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu - is there a good way to see how many SQLs it's firing? Currently I can just enable the SQL Debug where it shows the query itself, but are there any other Hibernate debugging tips I should know about? I do think I may need to override this find all so I only get the information I want from the relationships.

Comment: First thing would be to enable show_sql as in https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/. This would be a good starting point and subsequently you can tune you associations to LAZY/EAGER, SELECT/JOIN/SUBSELECT and tune these queries by running them from some DB editor by noticing cost/time for the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you are retrieving unwanted response and if you want to filter then you may use **@JsonIgnore**

eg:

```
  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity_1_id")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Entity1 entity1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers to consider:

1. Consider making associations Lazy by default unless you really want to load all the association data and its associations along the parent.
2. Use JOIN in HQL/criteria based on which association we really want to fetch and the depth of associations.
3. Or use EntityGraph to decide which associations to be fetch.
4. Enable `show_sql` as this show the number of SQLs and the exact SQLs that are getting fired to the DB. This would be a good starting point and subsequently you can tune you associations to LAZY/EAGER, SELECT/JOIN/SUBSELECT based on your use case.
5. You can run these queries against the DB and see if tuning the query/DB (indexes, partitioning etc) will help reduce the query times.
6. See if second level cache would help for your use case. Note that second level cache will come with its own complexity and extra overhead and especially if the data is of transactional type and not read-only mostly. With application deployed on nodes maintaining the cache coherence will be another aspect to think about. Need to validate if the extra overhead and complexity is really worth the efficiency outcome of the second level cache.
7. From an application design perspective, you can also consider and see if you really want to retrieve the MainEntity and the associations in a single request or UI. Instead we could first show the MainEntity with some paging and based on the selection we could fetch the associations for that MainEntity with paging.

Note that, this is not a complete list. But a good starting point and based on your use case you can see which one would fit for you and any other additional techniques.